# Retrieving error ate_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface

Tags: php, html, php-5.3

I would like to firstly adress that i have looked into previous threads that has given the answer, but upon implementing the solutions. I am getting the following response. I would be very grateful for any type of response, that is correlated to this issue.

```
                  **Project description:**
```

I have been assigned a task to calculate the time difference between todays date and the remaining days to halloween upon an input of a date from an user using a post request.

```
                         Fault codes
```

- Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface, null given in
- Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

  ```
          **Html code:**



  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Hallowen kalkylering</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta keywords="Hallowen, kalkylera" />
      <link rel="stylesheet"  href="stil.css">

  </head>
  <style>
      id {
          text-align: center;
      }
      button {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
      <body background="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/i.cdpn.io/328575.rrRQYW.2f211232-53fc-4b59-952f-baf9951e2cba.png">

      <div id="title">
          <h1 style="text-align: center; color: red;">Kalkylera dagar till Hallowen</h1>

      </div>

      <div id="Formular" class="formular">
          <form action="Kalkyl.php" method="POST">
              <center><label style="" for="idag">Dagens datum</label>
  ```

  När är hallowen?

  ```
  </body>
  ```

  **PHP code:**

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  ```

  Dagar kvar

  ```
  </head>
  <body>
      <center><p> Nedräknare </p></center>
      <?php 




      echo "<center>$idagny</center>";

      "<br>";

      echo "<center> men mamma hur många dagar är det kvar till hallowen?</center>" ;

       "<br>";
       $idag = $_POST["idag"];



       $idagny = new datetime("2017/10/20");
       $Hallowendatum = new datetime("2017/10/31");

       $dagarkvar = date_diff($idagny,$hallowendatum);

       echo $dagarkvar->format("%R%a days");

       "<br>"




      ?>



  </body>
  ```

Best Regards,

David

Comment: $Hallowendatum is not the same as $hallowendatum. They should both have the same capitalization.

Comment: Also, since date_diff will return false on failure, it would be wise to check that in your code. Have some sort of error handling rather than allowing PHP to fatal

Comment: So that was the issue... I am a beginner and now i can see that it is not sunshine and roses for developers! Thank you very much Erik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Hallowendatum is not the same as $hallowendatum. They should both have the same capitalization.

Also, since date_diff will return false on failure, it would be wise to check that in your code. Have some sort of error handling rather than allowing PHP to fatal